# No se ejecuta el procedimiento NotificationsRegistrationHandler

Tags: genexus, notificaciones

Desarrollo en Genexus 16u10 y tengo el inconveniente de que no se ejecuta el procedimiento, a pesar de haber revisado la documentación y por lo tanto no estoy guardando los tokens de cada dispositivo.
Las propiedades son:

```
Del Main Program:
Main Program = True
Enable Notifications = True
Notifications - Registration Handler = NotificationsRegistrationHandler
```

[image: Propiedades de procedimiento y generador]

Código del procedimiento:

```
for each
   where DeviceType = &DeviceType // enum domain SmartDeviceType
   where DeviceId  = &DeviceId   // Character(128)
   DeviceToken = &DeviceToken    // Character(1000)
   DeviceName = &DeviceName       // Character(128)
when none
   new
      DeviceType  = &DeviceType
      DeviceId = &DeviceId
      DeviceToken = &DeviceToken
      DeviceName = &DeviceName
   endnew
endfor
```

Espero su ayuda muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Que notification provider estas usando?
Segun las capturaas dice "None", deberias seleccionar uno y hacer la configuracion:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?33670,Notifications+Provider+property

Por ejemplo para OneSignal:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?33671,HowTo%3A+Register+an+application+to+use+OneSignal+services

Comment: Hola, no sabía que han respondido, continuo con el problema aunque me registré en OneSignal, ayuda por favor. Si me ayudas a resolver esto te pago.

Comment: Ahí está la configuración:


https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYMuE.png

Comment: En mi caso, luego de configurar OneSiganl comenzó a invocar el proc de registro.